# Remove rows with the help of pandas by conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have created some data which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Time': ['01.10.2019, 09:56:52', '01.10.2019, 09:57:15', '02.10.2019 09:57:23', '02.10.2019 10:02:58', '02.10.2019 13:11:58', '02.10.2019 13:22:55', '03.10.2019, 09:56:52', '03.10.2019, 09:57:15', '04.10.2019 09:57:23', '04.10.2019 10:02:58', '04.10.2019 13:11:58', '04.10.2019 13:22:55']
     ,'Action': ['Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed']
     ,'Name': ['Bayer', 'Bayer', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM' , 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'Treso', 'Treso', 'Geco' , 'Geco']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

     Time                    Action    Name
0    01.10.2019, 09:56:52    Opened    Bayer
1    01.10.2019, 09:57:15    Closed    Bayer
2    02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened    ITM
3    02.10.2019, 10:03:58    Closed    ITM
4    02.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened    ITM
5    02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    ITM
6    03.10.2019, 09:56:52    Opened    ITM
7    03.10.2019, 09:57:15    Closed    ITM
8    04.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened    Treso
9    04.10.2019, 10:03:58    Closed    Treso
10    04.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened    Geco
11    04.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    Geco
```

Now i want to remove the data by these conditions:

- if the time is under 5 mins between opened and closed and the same name, it should be deleted
- if there is an opened action and the same name and it repeats after the line closed and its on the same day -> it should delete everything  which has the same name
  betweeen the first opened and the last opened. For example line 2 until line 5 should be deleted but not until line 7 because its one day after.

The second Condition For Example: if there is this Input:

```
     Time                    Action    Name
0    02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened    ITM
1    02.10.2019, 10:03:58    Closed    ITM
2    02.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened    ITM
3    02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    ITM
4    03.10.2019, 09:56:52    Opened    ITM
5    03.10.2019, 09:57:15    Closed    ITM
```

My Output should be like that:

```
0    02.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened    ITM
1    02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    ITM
2    03.10.2019, 09:56:52    Opened    ITM
3    03.10.2019, 09:57:15    Closed    ITM
```

because it is the next day so from 2nd October to the 3rd and the others are under 5 mins

but if we have this scenario:

```
0    02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened    ITM
1    02.10.2019, 10:03:58    Closed    ITM
2    02.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened    ITM
3    02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    ITM
4    02.10.2019, 09:56:52    Opened    ITM
5    02.10.2019, 09:57:15    Closed    ITM
```

all of the data should be deleted except the second line and the third:

```
2    02.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened    ITM
3    02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    ITM
```

My wished output should be like this:

```
     Time                    Action    Name
0    02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened    ITM
3    02.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    ITM
4    03.10.2019, 09:56:52    Opened    ITM
5    03.10.2019, 09:57:15    Closed    ITM
6    04.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened    Treso
7    04.10.2019, 10:03:58    Closed    Treso
8    04.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened    Geco
9    04.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed    Geco
```

What I tried:

```
df_new = df.assign(group=pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).diff().dt.seconds.gt(300).cumsum()).groupby(["group", 
                                                                                                    "Time", 
                                                                                                    "Action",
                                                                                                    "Name"]).first()
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: are the open and closed always consecutive?

Comment: yes it should be everytime opened and closed, so they should be consecutive

Comment: It seems like `shift()` can handle the <5min condition if always consecutive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and how could I then add the second condition? :)

Comment: I'd use the groupby first() and last() like you started to. Just make your life easy and do it in two steps. Then after you have it working try to combine into one step with both conditions if it really matters to you.

Comment: can you have something like opened at 23:59 and closed at 00:04?

Comment: this timespan would not happen, because the last timestamp is 17:30

Comment: can you clarify 2nd condition?  in your wished output line ITM is included 4 times, but in your ask you indicated it should be deleted up to line 7 (or 6)?

Comment: So not correctly i wrote it should be line 2 until line 5 deleted. But not until line 7 because its one day after.

Comment: please edit expected output for clarity.  2nd condition is hard to understand

Comment: basically in 2nd condition you want to delete anything that had more than one 'Open' on same day?

Comment: I edited it. Please have a look.

Comment: in your wished output for ITM, date on 03.10.2019 is less than 5 minutes apart...  If I understand your logic correctly, NO ITM will make it though, because on the 2nd there are two entries over 5 minutes, and on the third the entry is less than 5 minutes...  You include ITM from `09:56:52` to `09:57:15` in every wished output, but it's less than 5 minute apart

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your logic requires:

1. eliminate everything that's less than 5 min apart.
2. from REMAINING values, remove those names that have more than one open in a day:

based on your data:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Time': ['01.10.2019, 09:56:52', '01.10.2019, 09:57:15', '02.10.2019 09:57:23', '02.10.2019 10:02:58', '02.10.2019 13:11:58', '02.10.2019 13:22:55', '03.10.2019, 09:56:52', '03.10.2019, 09:57:15', '04.10.2019 09:57:23', '04.10.2019 10:02:58', '04.10.2019 13:11:58', '04.10.2019 13:22:55']
     ,'Action': ['Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed']
     ,'Name': ['Bayer', 'Bayer', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM' , 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'Treso', 'Treso', 'Geco' , 'Geco']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

first do some conversion and sorting, to make sure the data is in correct order.

```
## convert time to datetime
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], dayfirst=True)

# get date
df['Date'] = df['Time'].dt.date

## make sure it's sorted by Name, and time:
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Time'])

## get time till next action for same client
df['time_to_next_action'] = \
np.where(((df['Name']==df['Name'].shift(-1)) & (df['Action']=='Opened')), df['Time'].shift(-1) - df['Time'], 0)

## convert time difference to minutes
df['time_to_next_action'] = df['time_to_next_action'].dt.total_seconds()/60.0

# CONDITION 1:

#delete entries under 5 minutes:

df = df[np.where(
    (
    (
        (df['Action']=='Opened') & (df['time_to_next_action']<5)
    )
    |
    (
        (df['Action']=='Closed') & (df['time_to_next_action'].shift(1)<5)
    )
    ), False, True
    )]

### explanation:  
## two possibilities: 
# 1. if action is Open and time to next action is less than 5 minutes delete it 
# 2. if action is 'Close' and time delta from previous action is less than 5 minutes, delete it

### CONDITION 2 edited based on comments:

## keep only first 'Opened'
df_first_open = df[df['Action']=='Opened'].sort_values(['Name', 'Time']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Date', 'Action'])

## keep only last 'Closed'
df_last_close = df[df['Action']=='Closed'].sort_values(['Name', 'Time'], ascending = False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Date', 'Action'])

## combine and sort the two
df = pd.concat([df_first_open, df_last_close]).sort_values(['Name', 'Time'])

# OPTIONAL: you can drop the extra columns:
df = df.drop(columns=['Date', 'time_to_next_action'])

print(df)
```

New output:

```
Time    Action  Name
10  2019-10-04 13:11:58 Opened  Geco
11  2019-10-04 13:22:55 Closed  Geco
2   2019-10-02 09:57:23 Opened  ITM
5   2019-10-02 13:22:55 Closed  ITM
8   2019-10-04 09:57:23 Opened  Treso
9   2019-10-04 10:02:58 Closed  Treso
```

For record, original condition 2 was:

```
## get date/name combinations that had only 1 'Open' per day:
df_to_keep = df[df['Action']=='Opened'].groupby(['Name', 'Action', 'Date']).count().reset_index()
df_to_keep = df_to_keep[np.where(df_to_keep['Time']==1, True, False)]

# those are the ones you'll keep in final output:
df = pd.merge(df_to_keep[['Name', 'Date']], df, how='left', on=['Name', 'Date'])
```

Comment: Thanks there is only one mistake! The less than 5 minutes should only be removed if there are only two values (open and closed). If there are more than two values ​​then take the first open status and and the last closed status and delete all in between.

Comment: ah...  that's a different thing.  I edited the answer